# Failing To Bind Multiple UI Components in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Alright I tried my best but looks like I need help. I have a textbox, a listview and a button in my xaml file. Listview has two columns: Devicename and DeviceAddress. I have done a binding of both the listview and textbox in such a way, that whenever I select an item in listview(I2CDeviceList), the deviceaddress(2nd Column) gets displayed in my textbox.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="AddressBox_PreviewTextInput" Name="AddressI2C" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.I2CDeviceAddress, Path=AddressMessage, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=I2cDeviceList}" />
<Button Content="I2C Read" Command="{Binding Path=I2CReadCommand}" Name="button9" />

<ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding I2CDeviceList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedI2CDeviceList, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="I2cDeviceList" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" >
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="I2C Device" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding I2CDevName}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="I2C Device Address" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding I2CDeviceAddress}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

Thus using **SelectedItem.I2CDeviceAddress** gives me the deviceaddress in my Textbox.

Now my view model has a property for the Button and the textbox and has the following method which gets invoked when button is clicked:

```
public void I2CReadCommandExecuted()
{
    ReadMessage = string.Empty;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[512];
    int address;

    string strValue = AddressMessage;
    if (strValue.StartsWith("0x"))
    {
       strValue = strValue.Remove(0, 2);
       address = Convert.ToInt32(strValue);
       mComm.setAddress(address);
    }
}   

// This is for textBox
private string _AddressMessage = string.Empty;
public string AddressMessage
{
   get
   {
       return _AddressMessage;
   }
   set
   {
       _AddressMessage = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("AddressMessage");
   }
}

// Property for ListView
public ObservableCollection<I2CModel> I2CDeviceList
    {
        get { return _I2CDeviceList; }
        set
        {
            _I2CDeviceList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("I2CDeviceList");
        }
    }

    // Property for Selected Item in ListView 
    private I2CModel _selectedI2CDeviceList;
    public I2CModel SelectedI2CDeviceList
    {
        get { return _selectedI2CDeviceList; }
        set
        {
            _selectedI2CDeviceList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedI2CDevSize");
        }
    }
```

Basically I have to remove the 0x from the value and store the hexadecimal value in my integer variable.

**Here I am facing two issues:**

1. When I put both **Text="{Binding SelectedItem.I2CDeviceAddress, Path=AddressMessage, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=I2cDeviceList}"** the seelcted address from the listview doesnt appear in my textbox. The moment I remove **Path=AddressMessage, Mode=TwoWay,**, it works fine. How to make sure both of them work smoothly? Is their any other way I can get the selected item from the listview and display it in my textbox?
2. By using string **strValue = AddressMessage;** I am trying to save the content of AddressMessage in the string but when I debug my code, it always shows "null" even though I have "0x23"(hardcoded) in my textbox. Due to this I get the following error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** at the beginning of **if** condition.

I tried my level best but it ain't happening. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no need to have seperate AddressMessage property. It can be done using SelectedI2CDeviceList. But still if you want to use it it can be achieved through below changes -

Set AddressMessage property when the selected item of listview changes

```
 public I2CModel SelectedI2CDeviceList
        {
            get { return _selectedI2CDeviceList; }
            set
            {
                _selectedI2CDeviceList = value;
                AddressMessage = _selectedI2CDeviceList.I2CDeviceAddress;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedI2CDevSize");
            }
        }
```

Also change the binding of textbox to below one:

```
<TextBox
                Name="AddressI2C"
                Text="{Binding Path=AddressMessage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Hence whenever selected item of the listview changes it will set the content for textbox and when AddressMessage property is properly set you want get your second issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I missed to remove ElementName=root from my sample code. Now removed it, it should work.

Comment: There you go :) Got it mate. I appreciate it :)